# Checkbox's isChecked getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I have an activity with 6 fragments(Swipe disabled). For each fragment I have 2 button( next and previous) which move to 1 fragment next and previous perfectly. I have 2 checkboxes which I need to check if they are checked or not before migrating to next activity. But I get null pointer because checkboxes are initialized in onCreateView Method but the fragment is loaded already due to viewpager. How can I check if checkboxes are checked or not?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step6, container, false);
    cb1  = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    next = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(cb1.isChecked())
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have implemented!

Comment: Problem is that view pager loads the fragment before the user reaches. So now when user clicks on next button cb1 is giving NPE.

Comment: ok, so what is null?

Comment: This is the error I am getting: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

Comment: so `cb1 is null`, so `v.findViewById(R.id.cb1)` returns `null`, so finally @cstew is right .... or you didn't provide your real code in the question...

Comment: But I have double checked the checkbox in fragment6.xml. It's there with the same id.

Comment: <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"/>

Comment: fragment_step6 <>  fragment6

Comment: Yes, fragment_step6. Can't it be a case that viewpager already loads fragment 6 when user is at fragment 5 or 4 and view is initialized already before a user actually views it?

Comment: **v = inflater.inflate(...)** then **v.findViewById(..)** => you see **v** there ...  so ViewPager is irrelevant ... and the only possibility(with given code!) is that `R.layout.fragment_step6` doesn't contain view with id `R.id.cb1` ... end of story!

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` will preload fragments for you and it's not going to remove old fragments from memory immediately. I do not think the problem is that the view is gone when the user clicks on the next button.

Check your layout file and make sure you have a checkbox in `res/layout/fragment_step6.xml` with the ID `cb1`.

Comment: it will do as soon as you started to slide left/right. best scenario is to use `setOffscreenPageLimit()`

Comment: the ViewPager is irrelevant and the second part of this answer is the key

Comment: Yes, I have defined the checkbox with this id in xml.

Answer (score -1):

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);//6 =  to the number you included in your question.
```

this will tell `viewpager` to retain your `fragments` while scrolling pages so you dont lost your state.

Comment: I have disabled swiping. The two buttons are used to navigate to next and previous frgament

Comment: when you click next or right you are actually sliding. so yeah!. you are scrolling to the next/previous.